Word switching from plural to singular when it is many?
In Shir HaShirim (5:11), Rashi writes:
"רְבָבוֹת הַרְבֵּה קְרוּיִין רְבָבָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר "רְבָבָה כְּצֶמַח הַשָׂדֶה נְתַתִּיךְ":
Many myriads are called ‘רְבָבָה’, as it is stated, “Myriads רְבָבָה like the vegetation of the field have I made you.”
So the plural word רְבָבוֹת becomes singular (רְבָבָה) when there are many of it. Are there any other examples in Lashon HaKodesh of a word switching from plural to singular when there are many of it?

In Hebrew, the uncountable noun is identical to the singular noun, and the intended meaning is based on context. In these cases, the uncountable noun is intended. (An uncountable noun is something like “foliage” as opposed to “leaves”, where instead of multiple individuals, the intent is the group as a whole “something”-ness).

Is this like fish in English?

It seems that the plural is dropped when the number of objects is large enough that the individuals are indistinguishable within the mass, in which case they are simply referred to as a single mass of x species. In the same way that Rashi (Bereishis 1:11) explains דשא as “vegetation” as a concept as opposed to individual “plants”, a hoard of men will be described as “man” (e.g. Shoftim 7:23 ויצעק איש ישראל - “the Israelite man rallied”.) In this case, “man” is merely identifying the species of which the mass is comprised.
Some more examples: ומלאו את הארץ חלל - “they filled the earth with ‘corpse’” (Yechezkel 30:11)
ולא ימיש מעשות פֶרי - “it does not cease to give fruit” (Yirmiyah 17:8)
וסוס ורכב רב מאד - “and horse and chariot, a great many” (Yehoshua 11:4)
The more difficult it is to distinguish the individual, the more natural this becomes. We would not expect the word חול - “sand” to have a plural form, because we are referring to the abstract mass, not just to a large group of sand grains.

This happens pretty frequently with nouns in Hebrew, when either a large unspecified number is meant, or a number larger than ten.
See eg Bereishit 32:6 or Shemot 26:19.

Thanks! The interesting thing about Bereishit 32:6 is that the word צֹאן
does not have a plural form at all; whereas , חֲמוֹר, עֶבֶד וְשִׁפְחָה do. Do you have any intuition as to why that is the case?

צאן translates as “flock”. Like בקר, you will never find a single ״צאן״. When referring to one animal it will always be ״מן הצאן״ etc.
